# I get an ERROR when installing CALENDAR 2.3.0

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

Below is the Error Code

Exception Caught
SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1072 Key column 'ics_url' doesn't exist in table:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exp_calendar_calendars` ( `id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `site_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL, `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, `url_title` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, `color` VARCHAR(7) DEFAULT NULL, `description` VARCHAR(300) DEFAULT NULL, `ics_hash` VARCHAR(100) DEFAULT NULL, `default` TINYINT(1) DEFAULT '0', PRIMARY KEY (`id`), KEY `site_id` (`site_id`), KEY `ics_url` (`ics_url`) ) DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci ENGINE=InnoDB;
ee/legacy/database/drivers/mysqli/mysqli_connection.php:122

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug with Calendar 2.3.0. We've since [released Calendar 2.3.1](https://solspace.com/expressionengine/calendar/docs/changelog/#v2-3-1), which resolves this issue. Sorry for the inconvenience.